# HTTP request getting partial response

Tags: php, http, request

I'm trying to get [this CrunchBase API page](http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/financial-organization/first-round-capital.js) as a string in PHP. When I visit that page in a browser, I get the full response (some 230K characters); however, when I try to get the page in a script, the response is much shorter (24341 characters on a server and 36629 characters locally, with exactly the same number of characters for other long CrunchBase pages). To get the page, I am using a function almost identical to [drupal_http_request()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) although I'm not using Drupal. (I have also tried using cURL and file_get_contents() and got the same result. And now that I'm thinking about it I have experienced the same from CrunchBase in Python in the past.)

What could be causing this and how can I fix it? PHP 5.3.2, Apache 2.2.14, Ubuntu 10.04. Here are additional details on the response:

```
[protocol] => HTTP/1.1
[headers] => Array
    (
        [content-type] => text/javascript; charset=utf-8
        [connection] => close
        [status] => 200 OK
        [x-powered-by] =>
        [etag] => "d809fc56a529054e613cd13e48d75931"
        [x-runtime] => 0.00453
        [content-length] => 230310
        [cache-control] => private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
        [server] => nginx/1.0.10 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.11 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
    )
```

I don't think it's a user agent issue as I used `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1092.0 Safari/536.6` in the request.

**UPDATE**

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/crunchbase-api/zgVExJlkPOU) I needed to add the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header to the request. That does result in a longer request result, but now I have to figure out how to inflate it. The [gzinflate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php) function fails with a `Warning: Data error`. Any thoughts on how to inflate the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comments in the PHP docs about [gzinflate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php), specifically the remarks about stripping the initial bytes. The [last comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php#33810) did the trick for me:

```
<?php $dec = gzinflate(substr($enc,10)); ?>
```

Though it seems that the number of bytes to be stripped depends on the original encoder. [Another comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php#77336) has a more thorough solution, and a reference to [RFC1952](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1952.html) for further reading.

Evidently [gzdecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) is meant to address to this issue, but it hasn't been released yet.

ps -- I deleted my comment about the returned data being plain text. I was wrong.

Comment: That appears to have worked. Thank you! Mostly-undocumented-magic at its best.